# How does GitLab add merged label to branch

Tags: git, gitlab

In our project there's a `master` branch and a `master1` branch.
When a new `dev` branch is merged into `master1` branch, GitLab won't add a merged tag to the source branch like this.

[image: what the tag looks like]

It seems that only the merge requests with target branch being `master` will have this tag and this really makes sense. My question is there any existing document on how this tag is added by GitLab?

Comment: Your picture is not showing properly.

Comment: Emmmm, it's just for illustrating what the merged tag is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a branch is `merged` or not, is determined by the branch that you have configured to be the `Default branch` in the project's settings. This is automatically set to be the first branch that you push, so usually `master`.

You can change the branch in the 'General Settings' of a project.

Comment: Is it possible to have a custom tag `my-merged`? And when a branch is merged into `master1`, this tag will be automatically added.